# is it possible in pure css to create a button that makes a link appear until we click on it?

Tags: css, button, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I have trouble in formulating the question, so sorry for that...
my question is about a menu, for context clarity

I try to create a button, or similar, when you click on it (:focus or maybe :checked) a drop-down menu appears with a link , this link is an anchor on the same page `#target`, and when you click on it, the drop-down menu disappears and you are sent to the target

With a checkbox i can make the menu appear, the link works, but the menu doesn't disappear when clicking on the link (in my case it's a problem since the menu is in position:fixed all over the screen)

With focus on an element, i can make the menu appear, and disappear when i click on the link it contains, but the link doesn't work, as if it disappears too fast to work

I can actually do it with visibility + transition, but i feel like it's a bad hack because i'm not good in css, there must be a clean way, right ?

```css
#target  {
    margin-top: 500px;
}
#hided_button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.show.normal:focus ~ #hided_button.normal,
.show.delayed:focus ~ #hided_button.delayed,
.show.check:checked ~ #hided_button.check {
    visibility: visible;
}
#hided_button.delayed {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<em>test with :focus on all kind of elements (it disappear well but link doesn't work) :</em>
<p class="show normal" tabindex="0">p_element</p>
<button class="show normal">button</button>
<a href="#" class="show normal">anchor</a>
<input type="button" id="input_button" class="show normal">
<label for="input_button">input</label>
<a id="hided_button" class="normal" href="#target">go_to</a>

<em><br>--------------<br>test with :focus and delay (it works) :</em>
<p class="show delayed" tabindex="0">p_element</p>
<button class="show delayed">button</button>
<a href="#" class="show delayed">anchor</a>
<input type="button" id="input_button2" class="show delayed">
<label for="input_button2">input</label>
<a id="hided_button" class="delayed" href="#target">go_to</a>

<em><br>--------------<br>test with :checked (link works but menu doesn't disapear) :</em>
<input type="checkbox" id="input_button3" class="show check">
<label for="input_button3">checkbox</label>
<a id="hided_button" class="check" href="#target">go_to</a>

<p id="target">target</p>
```